# Uploading Wordpress Images : error Permission denied in ....wp-admin/includes/file.php

Tags: wordpress

I have recently restored my wordpress (3.3.1) site from a backup.

All is working fine and i can add posts and pages no problem and attach/set images which already exist in my media library.

However, i can't add new images to my media library (wp-content/uploads).  I get error Permission denied in ....wp-admin/includes/file.php even though the permissions on wp-content and  wp-content/uploads etc are set to 777.  I even tried changing wp-admin/includes to 777 but that didnt make any difference.

Does anyone have any ideas.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a full file path for the uploads directory in Settings -> Media. I just ran into the same problem today and this fixed it for me.

It seems like this issue comes up when you've changed the location of the WordPress root - WP doesn't know where to create the new uploads folders so it returns a permissions error for whatever reason.